# Put the horizontal line in the header of moderncv *behind* the text?

Tags: moderncv, overlap

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\moderncvstyle{casual}

\firstname{Asdf}
\familyname{Xyz}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\photo[220pt][0pt]{example-image-a}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the letter "y" is overlapped by the horizontal line. I want it to be the other way around, i.e. the horizontal line should be behind the "y". How can this be achieved?

I am using moderncv 1.2.0, but I also tested it with 2.2.0, the results are the same.

Comment: With invisible rule
\familyname{\rule[-0.5cm]{0pt}{0pt}Xyz}

Comment: @pascal974 No, this offsets the horizontal line to the bottom, but I want to it to stay in the same position. As I wrote in my question, I simply want the horizontal line be _behind_ the "y", not below.

Comment: Sorry for my very bad English. I propose a solution by modifying a source file of the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By modifying (comment) the moderncvheadii.sty file line 134
   [image]
2. By positioning "approximately" the rule with the textpos package

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
   \usepackage{newpxtext}
   \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
   \moderncvstyle{casual}

   \firstname{Asdf}
   \familyname{Xyz}

   \title{Curriculum Vitae}
   \photo[220pt][0pt]{example-image-a}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{textblock}{0}(0,5.7)
   {\color{color2!50}\rule{21cm}{.25ex}}%
   \end{textblock}

   \makecvtitle
   \end{document}
   ```
3. [image]

Comment: Thanks, which version of moderncv have you tested this with? There is no `moderncvheadii.sty` in the version I have installed atm, but I can switch to a different version.

Comment: So turns out, in moderncv 1.2.0, the corresponding file is `moderncvstylecasual.sty`, and there it is line 95. A bit tacky (not liking that one has to tune the vertical position) but it works. Thanks!